# Find standard deviation of two 2 items assuming perfect positive correlation

Tags: probability

I'm working through some homework and one problem reads:
"Compute the standard deviation of the returns on the portfolio assuming that the
two stocks’ returns are perfectly positively correlated"

I have the means and the standard deviations of the individual returns, I just don't understand how exactly the perfect positive correlation plays into this problem, or how to go about getting a single standard deviation. If someone could lead me in the right direction it would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The returns on the portfolio is going to equal the sum of returns on each stock. So if the returns on one stock is represented by the variable X and the returns on the other stock is represented by the variable Y, the total returns on the portfolio will be X + Y.

We're then looking for Var(X + Y). There's a nifty formula that states that Var(X + Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2 * Cov(X, Y). There's another formula that'll give you the Covariance in terms of the Correlation and the individual Variances. Since you have the individual Variances for X and Y, as well as the information that X and Y are perfectly positively correlated (gives you the correlation), you can then find Var(X + Y).

Reference for formulas:
https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~hildebr/461/variance.pdf

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't made the connection that I needed that formula. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Let the two perfectly positively correlated variates be $X$ and $Y$.  Then because they are perfectly positively correlated we know that there must be some $a>0$ and $b$ such that given $x$ for the value of $X$, the value of $Y$ is 
$$y=ax+b$$

Then the standard deviation of $Y$ would be $a$ times the standard deviation of $X$.  Since you have $\sigma_X$ and $\sigma_Y$, you will know that 
$$a = \frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}$$

and the sum $X+Y$ has the same standard deviation as the variate
$$
x + ax+b = (a+1)x+b
$$
which will be
$$
\left(\frac{\sigma_Y}{\sigma_X}+1\right) \sigma_X = \sigma_X+\sigma_Y
$$
So that is the standard deviation of the portfolio sum.  Note that this can be significantly larger than the "no-correlation" value of $\sqrt{\sigma_X^2+\sigma_Y^2}$.